# negative exponent for BigInteger

Tags: java, math, biginteger, modulus

I am performing some arithmetic calculations in Java and met with a problem of using BigInteger to perform a power to a negative exponent (for deriving modulus inverse).

```
BigInteger x = new BigInteger("6");
x.pow(-1);
```

Of course, this caused at error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Negative exponent
```

Understand that modpow allows negative exponent but I am not using mod in my case. Is there any possible turn around to rectify this issue?

Comment: What do you want the answer to be? A BigDecimal?

Comment: If you are trying to do a modular inverse, use BigInteger.modInverse().   If you are not, then clearly your result will not be an integer, and you shouldn't expect a class named BigInteger to deal with that.  No?

Comment: *"BigInteger to perform a power to a negative exponent (for deriving modulus inverse)"* - I think you are looking for [`Java.math.BigInteger.modInverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for the prompt response. the equation deals with modulus inverse, but the final equation on paper is derived with an negative exponent. And yes, it will be BigInteger.

Comment: 6^-1 is 1/6 so a number between 0 and 1. What answer do you expect? 0?

Comment: ideally to include the remaining decimal, but in this case we can put it at 1.

Comment: "ideally..." doesn't make sense (remaining decimal? "it"?).  What answer are you looking to get for your input?  Can you give other examples?

Answer (score 0):

If worse comes to worse, you can always use a Maclaurin power series from calculus. The Maclaurin series for

```
   e^-x = 1 - x + (1/2!)x^2 - (1/3!)x^3 + ...
```

can be used to along with BigDecimal to get an answer for e^-x.